# RecyclerView item showing inconsistent data

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

While debugging my app, I noticed that my RecyclerView display is inconsistent with the data provided, i.e.

- If I set an alarm (TextView in RecyclerView has date set) then scroll my RecyclerView, the date shows up in the wrong positions e.g If I set the date on the 4th item, then the 3rd item **also** has the date set as well for some reason
- I also noticed that at times, e.g. Only the **3rd** and **5th** -last items in the data set plays an animation while the **4th does not**. I checked the logs, and it appears that onBindViewHolder() is not called for the 4th item, only 3rd and 5th. **Am I doing something wrong here?**

I have looked at the [documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/widget/RecyclerView.ViewHolder.html#getAdapterPosition()), but am not sure how to patch accordingly. Can you help me?

My onBindViewHolder:

```
@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(final RecyclerVH recyclerVH, final int position) {
    currentNote = data.get(position);
    final String currentTitle = currentNote.getTitle();
    final String currentContent = currentNote.getContent();
    final int currentPosition = currentNote.getPosition();
    String currentAlarmDate = currentNote.getAlarm();

    Log.d("RecyclerView", "onBindVH called: " + currentTitle);
    Log.d("RecyclerView", "Position at: " + currentPosition + " and Adapter Position at: " + recyclerVH.getAdapterPosition());

    // final Info currentObject = data.get(position);
    // Current Info object retrieved for current RecyclerView item - USED FOR DELETE
    recyclerVH.listTitle.setText(currentTitle);
    recyclerVH.listContent.setText(currentContent);
    Log.d("RecyclerAdapter", "currentAlarmDate is: '" + currentAlarmDate + "'");
    if (currentAlarmDate != null && !currentAlarmDate.equals(" ")) {
        Log.d("RecyclerAdapter", "Current Alarm set for: " + currentAlarmDate);
        recyclerVH.alarm.setText(currentAlarmDate);
    }

    recyclerVH.pencil.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Log.d("User Interface", "updateNoteInfo called!");
            // Opens Dialog to update Note and Alarm
            // TODO Open Activity instead

            //final View updateButton;
            // NEEDS TO BE DECLARED AT TOP, SO IT IS SEEN EVERYWHERE


            updateDialog = new MaterialDialog.Builder(context)
                    .title(R.string.rewrite_note)
                    .customView(R.layout.note_update_screen, false)
                    .positiveText(R.string.update)
                    .negativeText(R.string.nevermind)
                    .forceStacking(false)
                    .cancelable(false)
                    .canceledOnTouchOutside(false)
                    .onPositive(new MaterialDialog.SingleButtonCallback() {
                        @Override
                        public void onClick(MaterialDialog dialog, DialogAction which) {
                            updatedTitle = updateTitle.getText().toString();
                            updatedContent = updateContent.getText().toString();
                            updateNote(updatedTitle, updatedContent, recyclerVH.getAdapterPosition());
                        }
                    })
                    .build();
            //noinspection ConstantConditions
            updateTitle = (EditText) updateDialog.getCustomView().findViewById(R.id.updateNoteTitle);
            updateContent = (EditText) updateDialog.getCustomView().findViewById(R.id.updateNoteContent);
            // Set the text for the title using current info
            updateTitle.setText(currentTitle);
            updateTitle.setSingleLine(false);
            updateTitle.setInputType(InputType.TYPE_CLASS_TEXT | InputType.TYPE_TEXT_FLAG_MULTI_LINE | InputType.TYPE_TEXT_FLAG_CAP_SENTENCES);

            updateContent.setText(currentContent);
            updateContent.setSingleLine(false);
            updateContent.setInputType(InputType.TYPE_CLASS_TEXT | InputType.TYPE_TEXT_FLAG_MULTI_LINE | InputType.TYPE_TEXT_FLAG_CAP_SENTENCES);
            updateButton = updateDialog.getActionButton(DialogAction.POSITIVE);

            // TODO Use do-while loop for onTextChanged?
            // TODO Use Thread?
            updateDialog.show();
            // updateButton.setEnabled(false);
        }
    });
    runEnterAnimation(recyclerVH.itemView, position);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

since `RecyclerView` reuses or recycles the views, you must always add an `else` condition to make sure that it works properly. So, add an `else` block along with your `if` block.

Answer (score 1):

Remove the setOnClickListener() from onBindViewHolder and set the setOnClickListener() inside your ViewHolder RecyclerVH. To get the position of the clicked item or row call the method getAdapterPosition(). Example:

```
 public class ReservationViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder implements View.OnClickListener{
    // each data item is just a string in this case
    CardView cardView;

    public ReservationViewHolder(View v) {
        super(v);
        cardView = (CardView) v.findViewById(R.id.cv);
        cardView.setOnClickListener(this);
    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        int position = getAdapterPosition();
        // do what you want...
    }
}
```

Comment: This is helpful, but how do you know how to resolve my question?

Comment: Yes I have, it seems a more efficient setOnClickListener, but it doesn't seem related to the ordering of RecyclerView problem

Comment: It is related to RecyclerView ordering problem since the method getAdapterPosition() always returns the correct position of the item that has been clicked. Isn't your problem solved?

Comment: This onClick listener is used for updating the item, not setting an alarm for it. Sorry if I did not make that clear, but the problem I have is with the scrolling of the RecyclerView and how the data is displayed.